# background subtraction using matlab

Tags: matlab, foreground

I have a picture and I want to use only the foreground objects of that particulate picture. Now to use the objects I have tried `bwlabel()` but as the connected components are too big, its becoming tough to have the foreground image only. Besides that I have also tried to find the 'big object' from the image `[using max(cellfun(@numel,bwconncomp(BW).PixelIdxList));]`, resulting non-desirable outputs. Is there any way to find the foreground objects?